Trouble installing pytorch and cudatoolkit with conda (conda-forge)
I am trying to install pytorch using conda with the following command, as suggested by the pytorch official website
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge

And then I get the following result:

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(952): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_10'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_10
location of failed script: C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\envs\SelfIR\Scripts\.cudatoolkit-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 604, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 179, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "C:\Users\LuigiNixy\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 42: invalid start byte

return code: 1

()

I have looked over the web but have not found anything I could use. Does anyone have an idea of the right direction, or a conceptual understanding of what is going wrong?

Does this answer your question? Pyinstaller "failed to import the site module"
